# install.packages(“car”) on R 3.0.2 fails in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04, install.packages

I'm trying to do some linear regression models and I really need the package **"car"** but I can't install it.

> Warning message: package ‘car’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

Anyone knows what can I do to solve this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that your default repository did not have "car" package. Try

```
install.packages("car", dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

Comment: follow these steps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Your proximal problem is that [the current version of car on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html) depends on R >= 3.2.0.

Farther upstream, the problem is that Ubuntu releases ship with the version of R that was current at the release time, and R evolves very quickly. Your best bet is to follow the [updating/installation directions for Ubuntu on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html), i.e. add

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or via whatever package management tools you prefer), then `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

If it's absolutely necessary that you stick with that version of R, it's possible to download and install older versions from the [archived versions of car on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/car/), but it's a bit of a rabbit hole ...